# When should an italic font be used for newly-defined terms?

Tags: typography, italic

Let's say I'm writing a paper. In the introduction, I use some term informally, and then later in the text give an exact definition. Intuitively, I would use normal font for the informal uses in the introduction, and then italicize the term when it is defined. Is this usage correct, or should I italicize the first use of the term, and then simply use normal font when it is later exactly defined?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I am not sure this is the best place for this kind of questions – perhaps [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) would be better. While it is good practice to ask a general question, perhaps a more precise example would be needed here. What do you mean by formal and informal uses? Is it a word that has a "common sense" meaning and a specific, somewhat different meaning in your field?

Comment: IMHO, use emphasis for all occurrences until your term is completely defined.

Comment: @PolGab: This is not a good solution. It would overemphasize the term in the text.

Comment: @Mads Emphasising the word when you define it sounds like a good idea to me: you want the reader to pay attention. Informal uses of the word should stay informal and have no particular emphasis. Similarly, you don't need emphasis after defining the word unless there is an extremely good reason for it, and that does not happen often.

Comment: @ienissei: This is a good explanation. I think I will adopt that method in my paper.